# Rails 4.2.4 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LineItemsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails, learning on the book Agile Web Development with Rails 4, and using the Rails version 4.2.4 with Ruby version 2.1.5 . I'm currently at the iteration D3 and I got stuck with an error stated below :

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LineItemsController#create
Couldn't find Product with 'id'=

Rails.root: c:/Ruby on Rails/Agile Rail Development/depot

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace<br>
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:29:in `create'
```

Here is the link to the image of it : [Link to the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqIED.jpg).

And here I pushed the code to the GitHub : [Link to the full code](https://github.com/Maxwell-Alexius/Depot-Application).

This is my line_items_controller.rb file.

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def set_line_item
      @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    def line_item_params
      params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id, :cart_id)
    end
end
```

It would be appreciate to have your help, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no `params[:product_id]`

Use this

```
product = Product.find(params[:line_item][:product_id])
```

Comment: Sorry, but I got the error here, this is the error message : undefined method '[]' for nil:class.  I'm kind of like stuck with the concept of foreign key, is [:line_item] being nil?

Answer (score 0):

The error can be found in the line_items `index.html.erb` view at 
*app/views/index.html.erb* at line 34.

You have a little typo in there:

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(prodcut_id: product) %>
```

It should be `product_id:` instead of `prodcut_id:`.

The line should look like:

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The same problem encountered also with book "*Agile Web Development with Rails 6*" and
this code worked, line_items_controller:

```
    def create
if params[:product_id]
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.add_product(product)
else
  @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(line_item_params)
end

respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to store_index_url, notice: "Line item was successfully created." }
    format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

and system test case for it:

```
   test "creating a Line item" do
    visit line_items_url
    click_on "New Line Item"

    fill_in "Cart", with: @line_item.cart_id
    fill_in "Product", with: @line_item.product_id
    click_on "Create Line item"

    assert_text "Line item was successfully created"
  end
```